# How to apply autocomplete in a textbox of gridview .I am creating dynamic row of gridviwew

Tags: jquery, asp.net

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
                //alert('hi gridview');
                 $(document).ready(function () {
                     $('table[id$="gvProduct"] input.txtProdType').autocomplete({


                         source: function (request, response) {
                             $.ajax({
                                 type: "POST",
                                 url: "/Tally/SaleTest.aspx/autocompleteProdType",
                                 //data: "{'searchText':'" + document.getElementById('<%=gvProduct.ClientID %>').find('input:text[id$="txtProdType"]').value + "'}",
                                 data: "{ 'searchText' : '" + request.term + "'}",
                                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                 dataType: "json",

                                 success: function (data) {
                                     response(data.d);
                                 },


                                 error: function (result) {

                                 }
                             });
                         },
                         autoFocus: true,
                         minLength: 1,
                         open: function (event, ui) {
                             $('.ui-autocomplete').css('z-index', '99999');
                         },


                         select: function (event, selectedObject) {
                             jQuery(this).val(selectedObject.item.value);
                         }

                     });

                 });`enter code here`
```

and my asp.net design are

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvProduct" Visible="true"  runat="server" ShowFooter="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                                                <Columns>
```

<%--                                                        --%>
                                                            
                                                            
                                                             ' >

I am creating the dynamic row in grid view . The above code are for jquery and below are design of asp.net

Comment: <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product Type">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtProdType" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="txtProdType" ></asp:TextBox>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                            </asp:TemplateField>